# How so split a string of regular expressions without ruining the regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have an input string coming in the form of:

```
"Regular Expression Here", "Regular Expression Here",
```

How can I split this string into two strings representing regular expressions without ruining the regular expression in the case it has a comma in it? Is there a character I can split on that regular expressions does not support or something?

Edit: C#, sorry. I think the solution posted below about searching for the double quotes using regex maybe would work.

Comment: Which lang your running?

Comment: You have to encode your expressions in a way that can distinguish a `", "` that separates two expressions from a `", "` inside an expression. If you told us what programming language you are using we could give you an example.

Comment: This can't be done.. you're screwed. Anytime you have a string already in solution, and its in this form, I mean.

Comment: In general, you need to separate the regular expressions with a character that's unlikely to be in the regular expressions themselves. Since all characters are valid in regular expressions, there isn't an obvious candidate. You have to use your knowledge of the problem domain to determine the likely set of regular expressions and choose a delimiter based on that. `\0` (null) would likely be my choice, but like I said, you have to know the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `"(?<!\\)\"(.*)(?<!\\)\""` to capture a regular expression thats inside of quotes (assuming all quotes inside of the regular expression are escaped).

Or you can split on `(?<!\\)\"` (again, assuming all quotes inside of the regular expression are escaped)

Answer (score -1):

Split on something like `", "` then remove the leading `"` from entry 1 and `",`  from the last. this will only work if you have no `", "` in your regex but if you can't count on that I think you really are loosing irrecoverable information when you are joining them together rather than when you are splitting them back up.

Comment: The question specifically asks about the scenario involving having a `,` in one of the regular expressions (and it's not lost information, at least in this aspect, because it's still quoted).

Comment: So, does this solution work for you or are you open to another one?

Comment: I thought it was obvious the quotes were to be included in the pattern as I hadn't included them in the later quote. Thank you @Pipeline for pointing out what I was meaning(I would appreciate an upvote or marked answer if this worked for you. Though I also like the answers which offer encoding the regex first if it's an option.